# XSLT Transformation to output a element if not present in the source, if present leaving as it is

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing, saxon

Basically I have source XML

```
<RootElement attr=yes>
     <parentElement>
        <ChildElement1>some value in str</ChildElement1>
        <ChildElement2>some value in str</ChildElement2>
        <ChildComplexType1>
              <grandChildElement1>some value in str</grandChildElement1>
         </ChildComplexType1>
     </parentElement>
</RootElement>
```

I am using XSLT to change it to some other XML.
The consumer consuming the result XML expects as below

```
<RootElement attr=yes>
         <parentElement>
            <ChildElement1>some value in str</ChildElement1>
            <ChildElement2>some value in str</ChildElement2>
            <ChildComplexType1>
                  <grandChildElement1>some value in str</grandChildElement1>
                  <grandChildElement2>Default Value/ From Source XML</grandChildElement2>
             </ChildComplexType1>
         </parentElement>
    </RootElement>
```

The problem is I am using the below Matches rule and it is not working.
Can anyone suggest a better rule that works ?
I believe this is a basic question, Apologize since I am new to XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="1">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:parentElement"
        priority="2">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"
            namespace="http://namespace"
            inherit-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:namespace name="ns5"
                select="'namespace'" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*:ChildComplexType1">
            <xsl:if test="not(*:grandChildElement2)" priority="3">
                <grandChildElement2>defaultValue</grandChildElement2>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the use of the "priority" attribute on the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="1">
```

This has given it a higher priority than the template matching `*::ChildComplexType1`, and so this template is not ever matched.

Try removing the priorities, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:parentElement">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"
            namespace="http://namespace"
            inherit-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:namespace name="ns5"
                select="'namespace'" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:ChildComplexType1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:if test="not(*:grandChildElement2)">
                <grandChildElement2>defaultValue</grandChildElement2>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I added an `xsl:copy` to the `ChildComplexType1` template too, but you seem to be doing something with namespaces that you have not mentioned in your question, so you might need to change that to an `xsl:element` instead.

Note, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict for information on template priority. In particular, note how the highest default priority is 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you are using the Identity Template.

You could look at this page here which describes the template quite thoroughly.

http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity#s1.